# Overlay select in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a div which when clicks fades in an overlay image.

It works fine except that the first time it is called in Firefox the image is preselected with a blue opaque layer over it. Can anyone help me get rid of this, please?

```
$('.graphic-3').bind('click', function() {
        if ($('#popup-3').html() == "0") {
            $('.graphic-3-hidden').fadeTo(1000, 1);
            $('#popup-3').html("1");
        } else {
            $('.graphic-3-hidden').fadeTo(1000, 0);
            $('#popup-3').html("0");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was inadvertently resolved when I added an animation layer in the nest

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see your HTML and CSS code, I have found two possible source of error :

- I think it could be a matter of when you use your class `.graphic-3-hidden`.

  You need to set your opacity to 0 at start, otherwise it's going to 0 only when your condition return false.
- Otherwise it could be that your element #popup-3 does not contain a value.

In any case, it's hard to help without your html and css. A jsfiddle would be the best!